# Make main suspend

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor-client

In the [official documentation for kotor](https://ktor.io/docs/getting-started-ktor-client.html#create-client) , when creating a client, it is written to use suspend.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITdyf.png)

But I do not have such an item in the menu. What needs to be done?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TXG1.png)
Why do I need to use suspend at all when calling the kotor method?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Your question is unlikely will help others to find the problem, as it'll be impossible to find it by search engines with the current keywords. Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please rewrite it to be more clear, or remove it - you will be able to remove the question after you remove the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Kotlin's coroutine. What you are looking for is `runBlocking` function. It will block the main thread and run your suspend function calls.

```
fun main() {
  runBlocking {
    val client = HttpClient(CIO)
    val response = client.get("https://ktor.io/")
  }
}
```

Note: you should run the network request on the thread other than main thread, or the UI will be blocked until the request is finished.

See also: https://blog.logrocket.com/kotlin-suspend-runblocking-functions/

Answer (score -2):

You need to add the keyword suspend to the call function.